# Im trying to recreate spider square in unity but i cant figure out how to make the web

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As stated in the title. I will include a video of what I'm trying to make. I'm not sure how to make the part that the player swings on.
https://youtu.be/Z_RVr0nFpVE
Description of the mechanic: when the player taps a "web" is created that goes from the player to the roof at a slight angle forward. This web gets shorter over time. When the player stops tapping the web goes away.

Comment: You need to elaborate more. You need to show your attempt and where you are stuck. Do you know how to get the position of the web origin? Do you know how to get the position of your player? Do you know how to draw a line between 2 points? Do you know how to move your character with and/or without physics? Do you know how to get input from the player? There are so many small things you could do if you have an honest attempt at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m sure that there is no physical rope or string simulation. The easiest way is to slow the horizontal speed down, add decelerating up-directed velocity, and draw a rope from the origin to the player. After parameters adjustment the result should look similar to what you’ve shown.

Comment: This seems to work I need to spend a lot of time adjusting but that's the right concept thank you.